# 'X-Frame-Options','SAMEORIGIN' Cross Domain Iframe issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, iframe

I have 2 projects in node JS.
I have included the response to the header of my project is res. header('X-Frame-Options','SAMEORIGIN').

When I generate the source link and include it with the element , this link only working for my domain, I can't include the  with other domains.

How can access the  with a different domain

Thank you...!

Answer (score 4):

when it comes to security, I suggest using helmet.js.
So better install helmet.js then use it as middleware for security issues. For example write code below:

```
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");

app = express();
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    directives: {
      "frame-ancestors": ["'self'", "https://otherDomain.com", "https://www.oneMoreDomain.com"]
    }
  }
}));
```

ContentSecurityPolicy's frame-ancestors is doing the same thing as FRAME-OPTIONS, but you can add whitelist of domains which will have permission using frames.

Comment: leading wildcards are allowed `http://*.example.com` and if ancessotr is https, the child must be https as well.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of adding the `X-Frame-Options` headers is to prevent your page from being rendered within an `<iframe>` (or within a `<frame>`, `<embed>`, `<object>`). Based on the value of the header, you can prevent it completely or just allow embedding within the same origin.

So if you need to allow rendering your page from any domain, you can just remove that header from the response.

Please refer this for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Thanks @Udith Gunaratna, I have added the response header (res.header("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL") into the my iframe source, Now working fine.....

Comment: @ThamaraiKani `ALLOWALL` is not a valid value for that header. When an invalid value is set, browsers usually ignore the header, so I guess that's what happened in your case. So what you have done is the same as removing the header altogether.